# PHP Mysql select random rows from two IDs?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the row IDs of two rows, how can I in my query random between the two?

My query so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
WHERE user_id = '1' 
    AND active = '1' 
    AND id = '100' 
    OR id = '200' 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

So what I want to do is order by random between the row with id 100 and id 200.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses around the `OR` condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
WHERE user_id = '1' 
    AND active = '1' 
    AND (id = '100' OR id = '200')
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

`OR` has lower precedence than `AND`, so your `WHERE` clause was interpreted as

```
WHERE (user_id = '1' 
        AND active = '1' 
        AND id = '100')
    OR id = '200')
```

Even better is to use `IN`:

```
WHERE user_id = '1' 
    AND active = '1' 
    AND id IN ('100', '200')
```

Comment: if there's a pk on id this doesn't seem to work for me, I always get the same value - the poster wanted a random result between the two values

Comment: I get different values, see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93d70/1

Comment: Quite right, I had an error in my script. :)